# QTableView + custom TableModel + lazy loading

Tags: qt

I need to load heavy dataset into QTableView. Dataset is no less then 700Mb in memory and I don't want to load all it to memory.

QSqlQueryModel is not ideal for me for 2 reasons - it is not editable and it is not realy load-on-demand (because fetching whole data to memory).

**What I want to get**

- I want to store only some part of data in memory. Just for
  displaying and maybe some buffer for fast scrolling.
- Model should be editable
- It should be low-memory-consumption
- Should have no freezes

**How I am trying to solve this** (straightforward model of my code)

1. Custom QTableView (tableView)
2. Custom TableModel (model)
3. Model wrapper.    (wrapper)

Model wrapper select rows count from database, and set this value to model. Now model can answer for int rowCount().

This same value is set for tableView.verticalScrollBar().

tableView.verticalScrollBar signal(valueChanged) is connected to tableview slot(on_valueChanged)

**Some code**

```
tableView::on_valueChanged(value)
{
  wrapper.changeOffset(value);
}

wrapper::changeOffset(value)
{
  if (_offset == value){
    return;
  }

  _selectQuery->seek(value);    
  int endValue = qMin(value + _cacheSize, model->rowCount());  
  _list.clear();
  for(int i = value; i < endValue-1; i++){      
    _list.append(_selectQuery->record());
  }
  model->setRecordList(_list);
  _offset = value;
  model->setOffset(_offset);
```

}

_selectQuery in wrapper::changeOffset is previosly executed QSqlQuery cursor for select query results.

I also implemented several methods in model

```
QVariant SqlRecModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
{
    int row = index.row() - _offset;        
    if (row > m_recList.size() || row < 0){
        return QVariant();
    }
    if (role == Qt::DisplayRole)
    {
        QVariant value = m_recList.at(row).value(index.column());
        return value;
    }
    return QVariant();
}
```

Setter for model data storage

```
void SqlRecModel::setRecordList(const QList<QSqlRecord> &records)
{
    qDebug() << "r:";
    emit layoutAboutToBeChanged();
    m_recList = records;
    emit layoutChanged();
}
```

**Problem**

I can scroll _cacheSize rows, but I get crash (The program has unexpectedly finished.) after going out of old cacheRange.

Any advice? I don't know where to dig. Thanks!

Comment: If you get a crash: take out your debugger and start finding out _where_ the crash happens.

Comment: You're right. I'm on my way to install normal debugger. Current one shows ReadAccess error at 0x0. Exception somewhere in QSqlRecord         Qt5Sql!QSqlRecord::QSqlRecord: 0x675f71d0: mov     rax,qword ptr [rdx]

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for disturbing.

Error was in other code block.

This way is just okay to solve the task I have.

btw: if you play with cache buffer you can achive more smooth scroll.